# PanoramaBackground.png now showing as Background image?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not but when I run the Windows Phone 8 Panorama template project that comes with VS, the PanoramaBackground.png background image never shows - not in Design View and not in the emulator and not even on the device. Why won't it show? And how do we get it to show up?

[image]

Comment: could you show your `PanoramaBackground.png` settings?

Comment: @WiiMaxx - settings? In the properties pane of the selected image, the Build Action is set to `Resource` - if that's what you mean?

Comment: mhh sometimes it isn't set to `Resource` but in your case i have no clue what wrong

Comment: Yah me neither. I tried also setting it to "Copy always" as well as setting the Build action to `Compile`, `Embedded Resource` and all the others with no luck. Oh well, I guess I'll just have to settle with a white background lol

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

use 'Assets/PanoramaBackground.png' url

or

Solution Explorer -> click right mouse button on PanoramaBackground.png -> click Properties ->  set Build Action to Resource value